# Unicode to string

Tags: python

A function is returning sets of unicode values which I must convert to list of strings. How to go about this? For example, the function returns:

```
for items in someFunction():
   print items,  type(items)

>> 2016-06-03, 2016-06-02,2016-06-01 <type 'unicode'>
```

but then, I want results be returned as:

```
["2016-06-03", "2016-06-02","2016-06-01"] <type 'list'>
```

Comment: It appears `items` is *one* long string (`unicode` type) containing commas and several dates... Formatting that into a JSON array has little to do with the fact that you have `unicode` objects. Can you clarify a little more what you need to do, ignoring `unicode` for the moment?

Comment: [Read the documentation:](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.split#string-methods) "Below are listed the string methods which both 8-bit strings **and Unicode objects** support." ... (further down) ... [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.split#str.split) : Return a list of the words in the string, using sep as the delimiter string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

someFunction() is returning a long unicode as the first element, split it with ',' then strip it and do a list comprehention. Try the following.

```
a = someFunction()
b = [str(i).strip() for i in a[0].split(',')]
print b, type(b)
['2016-06-03', '2016-06-06', '2016-06-05', '2016-06-04'] , <type 'list'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your string into list using slpit() method of class string, Try the following code.

```
for items in someFunction():
   print items.split(','),  type(items.split(','))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to encode each value in the list to a string:

```
   item.encode('UTF8')
```

Then you can append to a new list and print it out.